# Why java doesn't recognize a variable?

Tags: java

Does anyone know why java doesn't understand the variable "increment"? 
I am tasked to find out the user's years of service and salary. After that, I will assign each of them with an increment. However when I want to print the variable "increment", java doesn't recognize it. May I know why?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Q4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         int increment;
        String yearsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please enter your years of service");

        String salaryString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Please enter your salary");

        int years = Integer.parseInt(yearsString);
        double salary = Double.parseDouble(salaryString);


        if(years < 10) {
            if(salary < 1000.0) {
                increment = 100;
            }

            else if (salary< 2000.0) {
                increment = 200;
            }

            else {
                increment = 300;
            }
        }

        else if (years > 10) {
            if(salary<1000) {
                increment = 200;
            }

            else if (salary < 2000) {
                increment = 300;
            }

            else {
                increment = 400;
            }
        }
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                 "Your increment is "+increment);

    }

}
```

Comment: You should get in the habit of reading the compiler's output.  A message like "error: variable increment might not have been initialized" tells you exactly what went wrong, and clearly has nothing to do with not "recognizing" a variable.  The answer to your question was right in front of you.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not the "recognizing" of the variable but its declaration.
You cannot use a local variable if the compiler considers that it may be not valued.

In the actual code, `increment` may not be valued as you assign a value to, only in some specific conditional statements.

So value `increment` in its declaration with a default value :

```
int increment = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of `increment` is not set for **years == 10**. Handle this condition properly.

Maybe you should use **just** **`else`** instead of **`else if (years > 10)`**

Comment: @davidxxx:  Have you tried it?  It does compile... without any -`Xlint:all` warnings, even.  The compiler (at least, the typical `javac` 1.8.* from Oracle) does indeed understand that `else` covers all other cases.

Comment: You are right. It compiles. I bad read your answer. I upvote :) But anyway it changes the logic of the code. Which could be undesirable.

Comment: @davidxxx  OK, _that_ I'll agree with.  Perhaps the first test should have been `if (years <= 10)` to assign the lesser values (this solution assigns the greater values when `years == 10`), or (less likely) perhaps exactly 10 years should be handled as a special case somehow.  That said, assuming `increment` should be `0` is _also_ changing the logic...

Comment: It is a domain/business case. So hard to guess exactly how handle this "hole" . Maybe it could be included in the > statement  or in the <  statement or still as a special case as you said. It is the problem with questions sometimes : they miss some information to give a really adapted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this may be due to the fact that the variable `increment` is never initialised. Can you try altering the declaration to:

```
int increment = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is having compilation issue. Increment variable is not initialized. Add a default value to increment.

```
int increment = defaultValue; // may be 0 or 100.
```

Also if years =10, then you are not handling condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your variable with a value.

For example:

```
 int increment = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value increment in it's declaration with a default value.

`int increment;` must be include default value like as `int increment = 0;`